# Input tag is defaulting value to False. How can I get it to null so that Placeholder can be shown

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So I trying to make my first project in React JS. I was making a register screen with few basic inputs.

Here is my RegisterScreen.js file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  MDBBtn,
  MDBContainer,
  MDBCard,
  MDBCardBody,
  MDBCol,
  MDBRow,
  MDBInput,
} from "mdb-react-ui-kit";
import axios from "axios";
import ErrorMessage from "../../Components/ErrorMessage";
import Loading from "../../Components/Loading";

const RegisterScreen = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [pic, setPic] = useState("");
  const [picMessage, setPicMessage] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [cnfrmPassword, setCnfrmPassword] = useState(false);
  const navFun = () => {
    navigate("/mynotes");
  };

  const SaveHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(name, email, password, cnfrmPassword);

    if (password !== cnfrmPassword) {
      setLoading(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setMessage("Passwords do not match");
        setLoading(false);
      }, 500);

      setTimeout(() => {
        setMessage(null);
      }, 2500);
    } else {
      setMessage(null);
      try {
        const config = {
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
          },
        };
        setLoading(true);
        const { data } = await axios.post(
          "/api/users",
          { name, email, password, pic },
          config
        );
        localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));

        navFun();
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error.response.data);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
  };

  const postDetails = (pics) => {
    if (!pics) {
      return setPicMessage("Please Select an Image");
    } else {
      setPicMessage(null);
    }
    if (
      pics.type === "image/jpeg" ||
      pics.type === "image/png" ||
      pics.type === "image/JPEG" ||
      pics.type === "image/PNG"
    ) {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("file", pics);
      data.append("upload_preset", "noteApp");
      data.append("cloud_name", "dbuwj7uyu");
      fetch("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dbuwj7uyu/image/upload", {
        method: "post",
        body: data,
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          setPic(data.url.toString());
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    } else {
      return setPicMessage("Please Select an Image");
    }
  };

  return (
    <MDBContainer fluid>
      <MDBRow className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <MDBCol col="12">
          <MDBCard
            className="bg-white my-3 mx-auto"
            style={{ borderRadius: "1rem", maxWidth: "500px" }}
          >
            <MDBCardBody className="px-5 py-3 w-100 d-flex flex-column">
              <h2 className="fw-bold mb-0 text-center heading">SignUp</h2>
              {message && (
                <ErrorMessage variant="danger">{message}</ErrorMessage>
              )}
              {error && <ErrorMessage variant="danger">{error}</ErrorMessage>}
              {loading && <Loading />}
              <MDBInput
                wrapperClass="mb-4 w-100"
                placeholder="Full Name"
                id="formControlLgFullName"
                type="text"
                size="lg"
                value={name}
                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
              />

              <MDBInput
                wrapperClass="mb-4 w-100"
                placeholder="Email address"
                id="formControlLgEmail"
                type="email"
                size="lg"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
              <MDBInput
                wrapperClass="mb-4 w-100"
                placeholder="Password"
                id="formControlLgPwd"
                type="password"
                size="lg"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
              <MDBInput
                wrapperClass="mb-4 w-100"
                placeholder="Confirm Password"
                id="formControlLgCpwd"
                type="password"
                size="lg"
                value={cnfrmPassword}
                onChange={(e) => setCnfrmPassword(e.target.value)}
              />

              {picMessage && (
                <ErrorMessage variant="danger">{picMessage}</ErrorMessage>
              )}
              <div className="uploadBtn">
                <label className="p-2 pictureUpld">
                  Upload Profile Picture
                </label>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  // style={{ width: "95px" }}
                  className="lefftt py-2"
                  title=" "
                  onChange={(e) => postDetails(e.target.files[0])}
                />
              </div>

              <MDBBtn size="lg" onClick={SaveHandler}>
                Submit
              </MDBBtn>

              <hr className="my-4" />

              <div style={{ display: "inline-flex" }}>
                <a href="/login" className="hyperlink">
                  Already Have an account?
                </a>
              </div>
            </MDBCardBody>
          </MDBCard>
        </MDBCol>
      </MDBRow>
    </MDBContainer>
  );
};

export default RegisterScreen;
```

and the CSS is as below:

```
 width: 50%;
 margin-left: 35px;
 text-align: right;
 position: relative;
}

.uploadBtn {
 padding: py-5;
 display: "inline-flex";
 border: #dddddd solid 2px;
 border-radius: 0.5rem;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.pictureUpld {
 text-align: center;
 color: #868585;
}
```

Everything works fine except the `Confirm Password` field. Which shows false (as *****) instead of showing placeholder on page load. Below are the Images on page load(1) and after I manually clear it (2)  [image: The error with the filed] [image]

I did check around,  removing `value={cnfrmPassword}` or setting it to `null` does work. But I don't know it's how I should be doing it

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize `confrmPassword` to an empty string rather than null to show the placeholder value.

The pattern of letting React manage the state of form component values is called Controlled Components (as opposed to Uncontrolled Components, if you were to not set the value and let the input manage it internally). Controlled components can be a useful pattern because they ensure stable values throughout the application lifecycle. Uncontrolled components can be easier to use with parent components and simpler to configure, but offer less flexibility.

See the React docs for the trade offs between controlled and uncontrolled components:

https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components#controlled-and-uncontrolled-components

See here for more on the Controlled Components pattern:

https://blog.logrocket.com/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components-in-react/